# Filtering by currency in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, spreadsheet, currency-format

I have this situation in Microsoft Excel:

[image: Data]

Cells are formatted by using "Format Cells" and setting the Currency manually for each cell. So, they are not simple strings. I would to sum filtering by currency. Is that possible? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### VBA

Because you used the "format" option to format these cells, formatting is not contained within the value of the cell, so we will need to define a function in VBA. Put this ([source](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showpost.php?p=2247921&postcount=5)) in a new module:

```
Public Function sumFormats(rng As Range) As String
Application.Volatile
Dim cell As Range, dblDollar#, dblPound#
dblDollar = 0: dblPound = 0
For Each cell In rng
If Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then
If Left(cell.Text, 1) = "$" Then
dblDollar = dblDollar + cell.Value
Else
dblPound = dblPound + cell.Value
End If
End If
Next cell
sumFormats = "Sum of currency: $" & dblDollar & "; Sum of Pounds: " & ChrW(163) & dblPound
End Function
```

Then use the new function `=sumFormats(A1:A20)` for whatever cells you want and it will give you the sums on 1 line. If you need subtotals on different lines, we will need to modify the output of the function.

---

### Non-VBA

If you don't want to mess with VBA, you will need a helper column next to your numbers. In that column use the function `=cell("format",A1)` and this will return `,2` for £ and `C2` for $. Then run a `=sumif` function for the subtotals.

`=sumif(helpcolumncell,"C2",currencycell)` to sum for dollars, and replace `C2` with `,2` for pounds. You can always hide the helper column if you don't like it. In this case we'll assume your data is in Column B and helper is Column C.

```
A             B    C

             Data  Format
              $1    =cell("format",B2) = C2
              £2    =cell("format",B3) = ,2  
              £3    =cell("format",B4) = ,2
              $4    =cell("format",B5) = C2 
sum dollar =sumif($C$2:$C$4,"C2",$B$2:$B$4) = 5

sum pound  =sumif($C$2:$C$4,",2",$B$2:$B$4) = 5
```

Then you will need to format these sumif cells to get the currency sign, or add in a `=concatenate("$"&sumif(...))` function

Comment: I tried both methods. With VBA I always end up in the ELSE block (pound) for every cell. Using the non-VBA method, `=cell("format",A1)` returns always `2`...

Comment: you changed the cell ranges to your ranges right? And you used per-defined currency formats? These both work when I use them, let's figure out the difference

Comment: I'm using € and HKD.

Comment: I don't know why, but Excel places an empty space (ASCII 32) before currency symbol. So, cell values are something as `␢€␢1234.56`. So I used `Mid(cell.Text, 2, 1)` instead of `Left(cell.Text, 1)` in the VBA code, and I solved. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!